# How to compare the beginning of an argument

Tags: context

I need to write a simple function in tex (ConTeXt more precisely, but I suspect that does not matter here), that does one thing when the first argument #1 begins with a particular string, and does something else when it does not. Like (in pseudo code):

```
\def\somefunction#1{
if (#1.beginsWith"fig:")
  do this
else
  do that
endif
}
```

How can that be done:

Comment: The command `\IfBeginWith` in package `xstring` may help. For details please see the manual. As the author says, `xstring` can work in plain e-TeX. So I guess it may help your ConTeXt file.

Answer (score 8):

Although pure TeX solutions are possible, I present a Lua solution. You can
use the function `string.find` and check if the argument starts with a particular string using the pattern `^fig:`.
The Lua function should be wrapped in a TeX macro. Here a full example:

```
\starttexcode
  \define[1]\beginsWith
    {\usercode{beginsWith(\!!bs#1\!!es)}}
\stoptexcode

\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or {}
  userdata.beginsWith = function(arg)
    if string.find(arg, "^fig:") then
      context("starts with “fig:”")
    else
      context("does not start with “fig:”")
    end
  end
\stopluacode

\starttext
  \beginsWith{Some text}\par
  \beginsWith{fig: A figure description}
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If the argument may contain quotes, then it is better to use `\unprotect\define[1]....beginsWith(\!!bs#1\!!es)}\protect`.

Comment: U+0022 is unlikely to appear in a figure description. And the correct quotation marks don't do any harm. But I agree, it's safer to wrap the argument in `\!!bs … \!!es`.

Comment: I would use `[===[#1]===]` --- that is exactly equivalent; uses the Lua string quoting directly instead of indrectly; looks nicer (in my opinion); and doesn’t require unprotecting.

Answer (score 6):

The question specifies ConTeXt, but leaves it a little open. For ConTeXt Mk IV a Lua solution does seem most sensible, as [Marco has answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128325). For Mk II, or indeed other formats, we need a TeX solution. Assuming e-TeX is available, I'd go with

```
\def\beginswith#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\secondoftwo}%
    {\doifbegins#1fig\blanktest}%
}
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\doifbegins#1fig#2\blanktest{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\beginswith{fig:stuff}{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
\beginswith{stuff:fig}{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
\beginswith{no}{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
\beginswith{ }{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
\beginswith{}{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
\beginswith{ fig}{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
\csname @@end\endcsname
\end
```

(Without e-TeX you need a slightly different 'blank test'.)

Comment: I should add that this is a token comparison, not a 'string' one: it's not clear to me from the question if this subtly is important.

Comment: Why not `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` instead of `\blanktest`? A non empty `#1` will *never* result in something `\if`-equivalent to `\relax`. And no `\expandafter` is needed.

Comment: @egreg I've modified: I tend to just use the test in `expl3` so don't normally have to remember how exactly it's set up. (Indeed, I'm not sure which version we have: might check and simplify if required¬)

Comment: ConTeXt provides `\firstoftwoarguments` and `\secondoftwoargument` that is similar to `\firstoftwo` and `\secondoftwo` defined above.

Comment: @Aditya I guessed it did had the same functionality: I decided to go for a 'general solution' as the question seemed to leave it slightly open.